# SQL LIKE Statement on a DateTime Type

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, datetime

How do you perform a `LIKE` statement on a column of `DateTime` datatype in SQL Server?

If I run the following SQL it returns me all the dates with 2009 in.

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable where CheckDate LIKE '%2009%'
```

However, if I want all the Oct, Nov & Dec dates I'd expect to be able to do the following:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable where CheckDate LIKE '%2009-1%'
```

But this returns me nothing!

I'm giving the user a filter option where they type in the date string and as they type I filter the data. So if they type '20', I'd like to return all the dates with '20' within the date (so this could be all 2012 dates or a date value like 06/20/1999)

Can anybody help?

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've updated the job with more detail about what I'm trying to do

Comment: Have you checked that your users want such a facility? I've never once wanted to find "all activity that happened on day 10 of any month, or in october, or in 2010".

Answer (score 22):

You can use the [`DATEPART`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) function to extract portions of dates. It should also make your queries more explicit about what you're seeking to achieve:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
where DATEPART(year,CheckDate)=2009 and
      DATEPART(month,CheckDate) between 10 and 12
```

(There are also specifically named functions, such as `MONTH` and `YEAR`, but I prefer `DATEPART` for consistency since it can access all components of a `datetime`)

You should try to avoid thinking of `datetime`s as having any kind of string format. Treating them as strings is one of the largest sources of errors we encounter.

Answer (score 10):

If you need to use `Like` operator (for some reason) you have to convert the `DateTime` column into a `varchar`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR, CheckDate, 120) LIKE '%2009-1%'
```

Answer (score 5):

*You can use something like this:*

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE CheckDate >= '2009-10-01' AND CheckDate < '2010-01-01';
```

Comment: And while you're at it - try to use a **language independent** date format - like `20091001` - that works for **all** language versions of SQL Server ....

Comment: Dangerous. Whereas the original query forced a conversion of a `datetime` to a string (and so will always produce a consistently formatted value), this forces conversions from string to `datetime`, and depending on regional settings, may in fact be querying for anything on or after 10th January 2009

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Isn't YYYY-MM-DD correct according to ISO 8601?

Comment: @Magnus - yes, it is. That doesn't necessarily mean that SQL Server interpreted such strings as ISO 8601. Certainly on older versions, and converting to `datetime` rather than `datetime2`, whether it interpreted it as YYYY-MM-DD or YYYY-DD-MM depended on regional settings. The only safe unambiguous date literal (without time) on those versions was YYYYMMDD, with no separators.