# Like operator in Datetime column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to use Like operator in a column of datetime. The values of the column is as follows:
2013-08-31 17:54:52.000
2013-08-31 17:54:52.000

My query is as below:

```
SELECT * FROM table where created_date Like '%54%'
```

It works fine. but when I search for '%52%' instead of '%54%', it gives me nothing. (It is working when I search till the minutes, but when I search for seconds or milli seconds it does not work.)

I have looked at the following url and it is working
[SQL LIKE Statement on a DateTime Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985536/sql-like-statement-on-a-datetime-type)

I want to know the reason, why this is happening and how like operator works with datetime type column.

Comment: If you really want to do it this way, explicitly call `convert(varchar(20), created_date, 121)`to make sure, that the correct format gets compared using `like`. But you better use Rahul's answer.

Comment: Can you explain what is the meaning of this type filtering?

Comment: 54 minutes, 54 seconds, or 54 ms?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan I am showing all the details in list view and filtering the records through javascript, that will search in all columns of list view. That's why I want to do this.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos 17 hours, 54 mins, 52 seconds and 000 miliseconds

Comment: Are you sure? What if you had `17 hours, 01 minutes, 03 seconds and 654 milliseconds`? You are on the wrong path here. No database uses text operators like `LIKE` on dates.

Answer (score 3):

I think it would be a better idea to use the [DATEPART](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) operator of SQL SERVER to extract the portion of date.

And example could be like:-

```
SELECT * FROM table
where DATEPART(minute,created_date)=54
```

**EDIT:-**

> I want to know the reason, why this is happening and how like operator
>   works with datetime type column.

Actually there is no direct support given by SQL Server for LIKE operator for DATETIME variable but you can always cast the DATETIME to a VARCHAR and then try to use the LIKE operator as you want.

**On a side note:-**

MSDN says:-

> DATEPART can be used in the select list, WHERE, HAVING, GROUP BY and
>   ORDER BY clauses.
>
> In SQL Server 2012, DATEPART implicitly casts string literals as a
>   datetime2 type. This means that DATEPART does not support the format
>   YDM when the date is passed as a string. You must explicitly cast the
>   string to a datetime or smalldatetime type to use the YDM format.

Comment: As you are saying there is no direct support for LIKE operator for DATETIME then why this operator is working when I search for minutes from the datetime column.

Also I want to search the string in whole datetime. I don't want to search in only date or minute or hours value.

Comment: Dates are not strings just as ints are not strings. There is no string to search with `LIKE`

Answer (score 1):

The 'LIKE' operator and any regular expression operators provided by other databases are used to process text values. A date is definitely not a text value, it is a separata type by itself.

It makes little sense to apply a text operator to a non-text type (like int or DATETIME or DATETIMEOFFSET), which is why you can't use `LIKE` on dates in any database. First of all, the values are not stored as text but in an implementation-specific binary form.

Then, while you can use `LIKE` on a specific text representation of a date, eg using CAST you have to absolutely certain what that representation is. Different locales display dates differently, with year first, year last, month first or last or whatever. What would you search against?

Moreover, what is 54? 54 minutes, 54 seconds or 654 milliseconds?

The only sensible solution is to use DATEPART to check specific parts of a date, or the BETWEEN operator to check for ranges.

Comment: @PenagiotisKanavos 54 is the minutes that is stored in datetime. I am satisfy with your answer.   
But my question is that when I search for the minutes from the datetime using LIKE operator then it is giving me the result, but when I search for seconds or milli seconds from the datetime it gives me no result.