# MYSQL Date query syntax not properly formatted

Tags: mysql, sql, validation, date, syntax

Here is how my column looks like

```
  deeday
 "06/07/15"
 "02/07/15"
 "06/07/15"
 "04/07/15"
 "06/07/15"
```

The following query works well

```
  SELECT * FROM Bango ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE( `deday` , '%y/%m/%d' )
```

What am I missing in the following query to make it work.

```
 SELECT * FROM `Bango` WHERE STR_TO_DATE( `deday` , '%y/%m/%d' ) = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%d/%m/%y')
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query can work as per below-

```
SELECT * FROM `Bango` WHERE STR_TO_DATE( `deday` , '%d/%m/%y' ) = curdate();
```

You can use as per below but it will kill the performance, so you can remove " from your field one time-

```
SELECT * FROM 
`Bango` 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE( replace(`deday`,'"','') , '%d/%m/%y' ) = curdate();
```

Comment: Thanks Zafar but strangely enough no errors and still no results for both queries. What should I be looking at ?

Comment: Even 'code' SELECT *
FROM soccer
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE( `deday` , '%d/%m/%y' 'code' works

Comment: what is data type of deday column

Comment: same result MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.0024 sec ).

Comment: i have checked and it is working perfectly, please check if your date string has some spaces etc. then you can use trim function.

Comment: No spaces its found in exactly this format "04/07/15" what I noticed first of all is that the double quotes are to be considered when querying other columns

Comment: plesae check this sql fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d9891/1 may be it helps you to identify your issue.

Comment: Got it its the quotes CREATE TABLE test (dt VARCHAR(25));INSERT INTO test VALUE('"06/07/15"'); doesnt work . How can I trim ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[SQL LIKE Statement on a DateTime Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985536/sql-like-statement-on-a-datetime-type)

If the column type is datetime the LIKE operator doesn't work without converting the value to a varchar string on the fly.

Comment: Thanks for the hint how about using an = operator in the query ?

Comment: Forgot to mention that the format in the Database is varchar.