# Passing datetimepicker value to WHERE LIKE clause in C#

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I have this query string stating stating at the below.

```
SqlComm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM MyDataTable WHERE (DataDate LIKE @SDataDate)";

SqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SDataDate", dtpSrcDataDate.Value.ToString());

SqlComm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM MyDataTable WHERE DataDate LIKE" + 
dtpSrcDataDate.Value;
```

Above two statements are not working.

When I tried the 1st statement the datagridview shows an empty one.

When I tried the second statement an error message occurs:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'LIKE7'

I can't figure it out the issue.

Please help.

Comment: What do you mean with applying a LIKE operator to a DateTime column?

Comment: Yeah LIKE might as well be = here if you are using date values. Otherwise you will need a range. You're missing a space at the end of the second statement so that one will never execute correctly as you are concatenating the value directly to LIKE. Post some sample data and table structure and you will get a better response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the [LIKE statement on a DateTime column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985536/sql-like-statement-on-a-datetime-type) and this doesn't make much sense, but, in any case you are using AddWithValue passing a string as value when a DateTime is expected

```
SqlComm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM MyDataTable WHERE DataDate = @SDataDate";
SqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SDataDate",dtpSrcDataDate.Value);
```

The second statement is another problem because you don't have a space between the LIKE and the value but, again, the DateTimePicker.Value is automatically transformed in a string by the concatenation and then this string cannot be used to search a DateTime column

In other words, use always a parameter of the correct datatype that matches the column type you are searching for. [Better also avoid completely AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and use

```
SqlComm.Parameters.Add("@SDataDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dtpSrcDataDate.Value;
```

Searching in this way poses another problem though. If your database column contains also the Time part then you can't search with just an = operator because you will never find a match.

For example, the DateTimePicker.Value is "23/07/2017 00:00:00" while the searched  record is "23/01/2017 09:35:00"

In this case you need two parameters. One to represent the minimum value searched and the other representing the maximum value searched

So, if you search for all records of a specific day you need code like this

```
SqlComm.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM MyDataTable WHERE 
                        DataDate >= @minDate AND 
                        DataDate <= @maxDate";

// Example dtpSrcDataDate.Value = 23/07/2017 00:00:00
SqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@minDate",dtpSrcDataDate.Value);
// add one day to get 24/07/2017 00:00:00 so you can search the whole 23th day
SqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@maxDate",dtpSrcDataDate.Value.AddDays(1));
```

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2013. So that if I use `SqlComm.Parameters.Add()` this `Add` is depricated in it. So that I have work with `AddWithValue()`. Also I have treied your solution but couldn't get the result expected. Instead of that I am getting an empty datagridview.

Comment: Even I have tried the below statements and couldn't get the result.


`DateTime dtsrcDataDate = dtpSrcDataDate.Value.Date;
                SqlComm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM MyDataTable WHERE DataDate = @SDataDate";
                SqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SDataDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dtsrcDataDate;`

Comment: The deprecated Add is the one that receives a Name and Value as parameters, not the one that receives the Name and SqlDbType. It has been deprecated for the potential error caused by the Value=0. Add with SqlDbType is the correct way to add a parameter to the parameter collection

Comment: The empty grid could be caused by the fact that you store your datetime values with the Time part not being zero. What kind of value are you trying to retrieve? Could you post an example? If there is the Time component in the value to retrieve and you have only the Date part then you need to query by range: IE >= minvalue AND <= maxvalue

Comment: Below is a sample record.
 ` 00000001 Processor 5/24/2016 100`

Comment: Can you confirm that the database field named _DataDate_ is of type DateTime or Date?

Comment: Yep `DataDate` is in date data type.

Comment: And the grid is still empty after you apply the code above?

Comment: Hi Steve,

many thanks for your help! Now the problem is sorted out. I am glad with your help I could solve the issue. I say thanks again.