# How to use LIKE with Date columns in Bookshelf?

Tags: postgresql, knex.js, bookshelf.js

When i try to use `LIKE` with `STRING` it will work correctly, but when I try with a `DATE` type column it will give an Error. This is my controller code:

```
router.route('/fetchStudentAttendance').post(function(req, res) {
  StudentAttendance
    .query(function(qb) {
      qb.where('date', 'LIKE', '"2018-01%"');
      // qb.where('remarks', 'LIKE', '"A%"'); // this is working
    })
    .where({'class_id': req.body.class_id, 'section_id': req.body.section_id})
    .fetchAll()
    .then(studentAttendance => {
      let content = {
        data: studentAttendance,
        success: true,
        message: 'Record Not Found',
      };
      return res.send(content);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      let content = {
        data: error,
        success: false,
        message: 'Error while fetching Student Attendance.',
      };
      return res.send(content);
    });
});
```

With the Date value it will output the following Error to the console:

```
code:"42883"
file:"parse_oper.c"
hint:"No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts."
length:202
line:"726"
name:"error"
position:"70"
routine:"op_error"
severity:"ERROR"
```

Comment: Is the `date` column a Date type?

Comment: Im surprised if that even returns expected results for ’remarks’ column due to strange extra quotes in the query... as devius is implying afaik like operator does not exist for date column type.

Comment: LIKE is for strings, not for DATE values. If you want rows from a certain date range, it's better to use a comparison with dates, e.g. `where date_column >= date '2018-01-01' and date_column < date '2018-02-01'`

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to do such check with

```
.where(knex.raw('to_char(date, \'YYYY-MM\')'), '2018-01')
```

Which provide following query

```
where to_char(date, 'YYYY-MM') = '2018-01'
```

You can read about date formatting functions on their [official documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html), there are a lot of functions and examples.

Comment: You can use `.whereRaw('...')` as a shortcut to `.where(knex.raw('...'))`.

Answer (score 1):

LIKE is for string values, not for DATE (or timestamp or number) values.

If you want rows from a certain date range, it's better to use a comparison with dates,

```
where date_column >= date '2018-01-01' and date_column < date '2018-02-01'
```

I don't know Knex, but there must be a way to specify a condition like that.

That has the added benefit, that the database is able to use an index on `date_column`.

Answer (score 0):

LIKE is for strings only. From the Postgres documentation:

> The LIKE expression returns true if the string matches the supplied
>   pattern

see: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html

To get around this limitation you would either need to store your dates as a string type in the database, or use a raw query to translate the database date field into a string with a db function (I'm not sure which function?) and then use the LIKE operator on that string.

Edit: Oh, found an SQL example for translating a DateTime (not sure this is your date type?) to a string and LIKE -ing it. (at question: [SQL LIKE Statement on a DateTime Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985536/sql-like-statement-on-a-datetime-type) )

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR, CheckDate, 120) LIKE '%2009-1%'`
```

Happy coding! Gary.

Comment: i know the SQL query, but i want to convert this in BOOKSHELF JS

Comment: So you want to convert the date column to a string and use the `LIKE` operator on the result, and you want to do that with Bookshelf?

Comment: @devius YES, exactly i want to do Same.

Comment: Then @coockoo's answer below is exactly what you're looking for. However this is the worst way to compare dates. Also, this isn't using Bookshelf in any way, since it's just accessing the query builder directly.

Comment: That SQL query invalid for Postgres

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query, using bookshelf and Knex it worked on column 'created_at' type timestamp, with having the date like '2019-07-05 11:56:30'.

```
    Db_model.query(qb =>{
        qb.where('created_at', 'LIKE', '2019-07%')
    })
    .fetchPage({
        pageSize: 15,
        page: 1,
    })
    .then(function (results) {
        console.log(result)
    }).catch((error)=>{
        console.log(error)

    })
```